# how to copy cells from sheet 1 to sheet 2 without removing data on sheet 2

Tags: vba, excel

I need code, as my title suggests, for the following task. I already tried a lot of different code but it's still not working.
[image]
I only need to move 2 columns, "SKU" and "Discount", into sheet2 using command button and delete it right away.

I'm already okay for this coding. However, but the problem is just beginning.
[image]
When I succeed to moved the first data, and try to move the 2nd data, the 1st data disappears.

I already tried many ways but still can't figure it out what's wrong with the code.

Please check the following code:

```
Sub OUTGOING_GOODS()
function1
function2
clear
Range_End_Method
End Sub

Sub function1()
Sheets("Invoice Print").Range("B21:B27").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Outgoing Goods").Range("D4")
End Sub

Sub function2()
Sheets("Invoice Print").Range("D21:D27").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Outgoing Goods").Range("L4")
End Sub

Sub clear()
Range("B21:B27").clear
End Sub
```

I also need to change the range for input data as well. As you can see the Range is defined only from D21:D27, but I need more than row 27 just in case there is additional data inputted.

Already tried the following code:

```
 With Worksheets("Sheet2")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
    For Each cell In Range("D4:D" & LastRow)
    DestinationRow = LastRow + 1
    Next
    For Each cell In Range("L4:L" & LastRow)
    DestinationRow = LastRow + 1
    Next
End With
```

And

```
Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 1 To InputData
            Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            For j = 1 To 3
                    .Cells(lastrow + 1, j).Value = InputData(i, j)
            Next j
        Next i
    End With
```

This still isn't working.

Comment: Which version of your code would you prefer we look at? There are different possible issues with each. A general issue I see in both is that you reference `Cells` & `Ranges` without always including a `Worksheet`. Since your macro is inherently working with 2 sheets this is a big way to have things go wrong.

Comment: the first code already succeed. but when i want to revised or add another code there is always an error.

Comment: I would suggest making sure to add the missing sheet references and instead of using `Destination` use `Sheets("Outgoing Goods").Range("D4").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll`. Let us know if that works.

Comment: What should i do to add data on sheet 2 without deleting previous data? please help

Comment: `Sheets("Invoice Print").Range("B21:B27").Copy` followed by `Sheets("Outgoing Goods").Range("D4").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll` would copy data from Invoice Print to Outgoing Goods without making any changes to Invoice Print

Comment: Sorry @Jmichael what i meant is add data on Outgoing Goods without deleting the previous data. So the data from Invoice print will add to new row in Outgoing goods.

Comment: Your Code using `.End(xlUp).Row` would get it. I would suggest tweaking the syntax to `LastRow = Worksheets("Outgoing Goods").Range("D1048576").End(xlUp).Row`. `Range` is just a cleaner look than `Cells` (personal opinion). I'm not sure why what you have now doesn't work since the snippets make it hard to tell what sheet `.Cells` would be referring to, but at the least, using 1 as your column reference means your looking at column A instead of D (thus why Range is clearer)

Comment: "Range("D1048576")" is this correct or misstype?

Comment: Hi @JMichael , already try the code but still not working. This is the new code after revision :                                                                             Sub OUTGOING_GOODS()
function1
function2
clear
End Sub

Sub function1()
Sheets("Invoice Print").Range("B21:B27").Copy
'Next row' Sheets("Outgoing Goods").Range("D4").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
LastRow = Worksheets("Outgoing Goods").Range("D1048576").End(xlUp).Row

End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our discussions thus far I'd suggest the following:

```
Sub Outgoing_Goods_New()
'
Dim Outgoing As Worksheet 'Generally it's better to use Worksheet variables. Saves the trouble of having to re-type the sheet name each time you reference the sheet
Dim Invoice As Worksheet
Dim LastRow_Invoice As Long
Dim LastRow_Outgoing As Long
Set Outgoing = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Outgoing Goods")
Set Invoice = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Invoice Print")

'Find the last row of Outgoing column D that's used so we know where to paste the new set of outgoing goods
LastRow_Outgoing = Outgoing.Range("D1048576").End(xlUp).Row

'Make sure column L of Outgoing ends at the same point
If Outgoing.Range("L1048576").End(xlUp).Row > LastRow_Outgoing Then
    LastRow_Outgoing = Outgoing.Range("L1048576").End(xlUp).Row
End If 'else column L's last used row is farther up the worksheet or the same row. Either way no need to update the value

'Determine how much data to copy
LastRow_Invoice = Invoice.Range("B1048576").End(xlUp).Row 'I'm assuming Column D of Invoice Print has to end at the same row. If not, use the same IF statement as above, but
    'checking column D of Invoice

'Copy the data from column B
Invoice.Range("B2:B" & LastRow_Invoice).Copy

'Paste to Outgoing Goods
Outgoing.Range("B" & LastRow_Outgoing).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

'Copy Column D of Invoice
Invoice.Range("D2:D" & LastRow_Invoice).Copy
Outgoing.Range("L" & LastRow_Outgoing).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

'Clear the data from Invoice print
Invoice.Range("B2:B" & LastRow_Invoice).ClearContents 'Removes the Value, but leaves formatting, comments, etc. alone

End Sub
```

This is mostly the logic you already had, but I did some clean-up to remove ambiguities and genericize the logic a little. Also, notice that I didn't keep the separate Subs. With how little you're doing there's just not any benefit to parsing the logic, especially with none of the code being re-used.

Last, I didn't delete column D on Invoice Print assuming that the cells just held formulas that pull in new data based on the values in Column B. If that's not the case, it seems like you should add a second `ClearContents` to delete Column D as well, but that's not certain given the vagueness of your use case.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I already have the answer. However, it still need to fixed a little bit since the output for this code `If Outgoing.Range("L1048576").End(xlUp).Row > LastRow_Outgoing Then
    LastRow_Outgoing = Outgoing.Range("L1048576").End(xlUp).Row
End If`